# The word for something which you can tell/guess just by seeing

Tags: word-request

What is the word for something which you can guess/tell just by seeing?

Example:
Person 1: I got these tattoos when I was young.
Person 2: It’s...(the word) without being told. Now they are fading.

Comment: Obvious, perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "Obvious", ***obviously**!*

Comment: Obvious, clear, apparent...

Answer (score 2):

Obvious is the most natural single word that comes to mind:

> *1. adjective*
>
> If something is obvious, it is easy to see or understand.

But note that you may come across as rude if the exchange was as blunt as:

> **A:** I got these tattoos when I was young
>
> **B:** That's obvious, now they are fading

As obvious also has a second meaning:

> 2. adjective
>
> If you describe something that someone says as obvious, you are being critical of it because you think it is unnecessary or shows lack of imagination.

(Both definitions from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obvious).)

So I wouldn't use "it's/that's obvious" as a direct reply to someone, to avoid this 'critical' interpretation. The same applies to some degree with other synonyms of obvious, e.g. [self-evident](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-evident).

For a direct reply to someone, I would probably say "I can tell"/"I could tell":

> **A:** I got these tattoos when I was young
>
> **B:** I could tell as they're starting to fade now.

Both have pretty much the same meaning, but 'I could tell' implies "I could tell [even before you told me]" whereas 'I can tell' could be 'I can tell [now that you've pointed it out to me]'.